# Float Variable Not Working Inside Switch Statment

Tags: c++, variables, switch-statement

So this program is supposed to collect weather temperatures over 7 days using a for loop and then basically just print them back out to the user with an average temperature and the highest recorded temperature. Keep in mind, the following piece of code is a part of a much larger program. Anyway, the problem seems to be the "highest_temp1" float variable. When I run the program it produces some sort of error code instead of the highest temperature. This piece of code was tested in a separate source file and it works no problem.

```
switch (choice)
    {
    case 3:
        int n;
        float temperatures [7];
        float lastweektemp [7] = {12.56,8.65,7.5,10,7.9,5,8};
        float highest_temp1, highest_temp2;
        float accumulated_temp1, accumulated_temp2;

        system("CLS");
        cout << "____________Weather Data____________" << endl << endl;
        for (n = 0; n<7; n++)
        {
            cout << "What is the temperature for Day " << n+1 << " ?" << endl;
            cin >> temperatures[n];
            if (highest_temp1 < temperatures [n])
            {
                highest_temp1 = temperatures [n];
            }
            if (highest_temp2 < lastweektemp [n])
            {
                highest_temp2 = lastweektemp [n];
            }

           accumulated_temp1 = accumulated_temp1 + temperatures[n];
           accumulated_temp2 = accumulated_temp2 + lastweektemp [n];
        }

        cout << endl << " Day    This Week    Last Week" << endl;

        for (n=0; n<7; n++)
        {
            cout << n+1 << temperatures[n] << lastweektemp[n] << endl;
        }

        system("CLS");
        cout << "              Weather Report" << endl;
        cout << "              --------------" << endl << endl;
        cout << "Current Week: " << endl;
        cout << "-------------" << endl;
        for (n=0; n<7; n++)
        {
            cout << "Day " << n+1 << ": " << temperatures[n] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "          Average: " << accumulated_temp1 / 7 << endl;
        cout << "          Highest Temperature: " << highest_temp1 << endl;

        cout << "Last Week: " << endl;
        cout << "----------" << endl;
        for (n=0; n<7; n++)
        {
            cout << "Day " << n+1 << ": " << lastweektemp[n] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << "          Average: " << accumulated_temp2 / 7 << endl;
        cout << "          Highest Temperature: " << highest_temp2 << endl;

        system("PAUSE");


    }
```

The highest temperature in current week is 24 but it is printing "Highest Temperature: 3.45857e+032" 
This exact 'error-code' is appearing every time I run the program it doesn't change.

I am a newbie hence why I can't upload a photo.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm doing a small assignment in college. This is my first question so go easy !!

Comment: _" am a newbie hence why I can't upload a photo."_ So you can copy the text of your error code here into your question. We don't want it as a picture anyway.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger to see exactly where you're using uninitialised variables. Also, enable compiler warnings to tell you the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not assigned any value to teh variable highest_temp1 and you are comparing it with another value.

Basically you will need to assign it a value first before you compare..

```
highest_temp1 = 10.00
```

(or anything that it is supposed to contain)

Comment: Thanks man I set it to zero. "highest_temp1 = 0;" and it worked perfect. Just a quick question. How come this program runs when it is executed in its own source file without initializing the 'highest_temp1 variable? Seriously C++ is my first language you must understand if I'm confused.

Comment: because without any initialization the float variable by default contains some value (+/- 3.4e +/- 38 (~7 digits)) ..So on runtime it doesnt show any error  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised `highest_temp1` (or `highest_temp1` for that matter: after that I stopped looking).

Answer (score 0):

Same for accumulated_temp, which gets not initialised. can be done via

```
float accumulated_temp1(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize variables before using them

```
float highest_temp1(-FLT_MAX);  // -FLT_MAX insures results of first compare
float highest_temp2(-FLT_MAX);  // Could use -1.0/0.0 of -INFINITY instead
float accumulated_temp1(0.0);
float accumulated_temp2(0.0);
```

Answer (score -1):

For float number condition use if statements switch is not able to work in case of float number, switch only work for integer number.